# How is a database schema change applied in entity framework using code first without migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

I do not want to use migrations at the moment but code first.

When I use the modelbuilder and the Fluent API to create a new table with database properties.

How do I say "apply changes now". Are the changes executed when the first query hits the database? Or is there any other better approach?

Comment: code first and migrations are not exclusive to each other.

Comment: That means I have to use them together?

Comment: no... they don't do the same thing, so using one doesn't mean you can't use the other, the way your question suggests.

Comment: OK but still what are the ways then to apply changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple [Database Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323(v=vs.113).aspx) at your disposal.  Which one you choose to use will vary depending on your overall development goals.

The [`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx) initializer is the most flexible of your options, offering you the ability to incrementally add to your model.  This "Migration" process is also sometimes referred to as "Data Motion".

Another option available to you is [`CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679221(v=vs.113).aspx), which is the Default strategy.  In this strategy, the first time you access any class which requires database access, the database will be created if it doesn't exist.  If the database already exists, nothing will happen.  If the schema of the database does not match the model, the transaction will fail and an error will be thrown.

Another popular initializer is [`DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604(v=vs.113).aspx).  This is an implementation of `IDatabaseInitializer` that will DELETE, recreate, and optionally re-seed the database only if the model has changed since the database was created.

Lastly, you have [`DropCreateDatabaseAlways`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679506(v=vs.113).aspx).  As you may expect, this is an implementation of `IDatabaseInitializer` that will always recreate and optionally re-seed the database the first time that a context is used in the app domain.